# Data Table parametros enviar y recibir

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatable

Buenas tengo una consulta estoy trabajando con codeigniter y datatable la cuestion es que yo creo una tabla con cursos, tiene un boton que envia al otra pagina el id, la cuestion es que necesito ver los alumnos de ese curso en otra tabla pero no puedo cargar la tabla ya que en la url me falta el id y no se como hacer para que pueda visualizarlo, les paso el codigo de mi js de la tabla curso donde se hace el envio y de la tabla alumnos donde esta mi problema

var table6;

```
DataTable=$('tblcursoalumno').DataTable();

  var table6 =$('#tblcursoalumno').DataTable({

    "language": {
       "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
        "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
        "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
        "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
        "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
        "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
        "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
        "sInfoPostFix":    "",
        "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
        "sUrl":            "",
        "sInfoThousands":  ",",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "oPaginate": {
          "sFirst":    "Primero",
          "sLast":     "Último",
          "sNext":     "Siguiente",
          "sPrevious": "Anterior"
      },
      "oAria": {
          "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
          "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
        }

     },

    "ajax":{
        "url":"http://localhost:8000/tesis/alumno/alumnocursoall",
        "type":"POST",
        "rowId": "#",
        "dataSrc": "",
        error:function(){
                alert('No hay Netbook para modificar');
            },
        },


    "columns": [
      { "data": "id", "visible": false },    

        { "data": "anio" },       
         { "data": "division" },             

        {"orderable": true,
            render:function(data, type, row){
             return  '<span >' +                      
                  ' <a href="'+baseurl+'alumno/editalumnocurso/'+row.id+'" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Seleccionar</a>'+
                  '  <span ></span>' +
                  '  </button>' 
            }
          }                                                 
        ] ,         



    "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
} );
```

var table8;

// $(document).ready(function() {

```
DataTable=$('tblalumnocursosreg').DataTable();

  var table8 =$('#tblalumnocursosreg').DataTable({

    "language": {
       "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
        "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
        "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
        "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
        "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
        "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
        "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
        "sInfoPostFix":    "",
        "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
        "sUrl":            "",
        "sInfoThousands":  ",",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "oPaginate": {
          "sFirst":    "Primero",
          "sLast":     "Último",
          "sNext":     "Siguiente",
          "sPrevious": "Anterior"
      },
      "oAria": {
          "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
          "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
        }

     },

    "ajax":{
        "url":"http://localhost:8000/tesis/alumno/alumnoscursos", //aca esta el problema me falta el id como puedo hacer porque deberia ser http://localhost:8000/tesis/alumno/alumnoscursos/iddelcurso no se como hacerlo necesito ayuda
        "type":"POST",            
        "rowId": "#",
        "dataSrc": "",
        error:function(){
                alert('No hay alumnos en estado regular');
            },
        },


    "columns": [
     { "data": "id", "visible": false },
       {
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": '',
            "className": "select-checkbox",
            "orderable": false
        },    

        { "data": "persona_name" },
        { "data": "persona_dni" },            
        { "data": "curso_anio" }, 
        { "data": "curso_division" },             
        { "data": "ciclolectivo" },                                         

        ] ,         

      "select": {
        "style":    'multi',
        "selector": 'td:first-child'
    },

    "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
} );
```

Comment: Se lo que quieres realizar, pero hace falta que seas mas especifico y que detalles lo que has intentado realizar para que se te pueda dar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: En que sentido mas especifica, la cuestion es que necesito cargar la tabla pero no lo hace por el tema ese del id y no se como agregarlo al datetable de la url para que me lo tome

Comment: Hola, por lo que entiendo hay unos pequeños detalles que te pueden ser utilices, si vas mandar el id por url el type deberia de ser GET en ves del POST (es mas, creo que no hay necesidad de ello pero bueno), lo otro, porque no metes el datatable8 en una funcion con un onclick? asi podrias pasar el row.id a esa funcion y cada vez que hagas un click en el boton haces la peticion y cargas los datos en el datatable.